# SwiftUI - Complex scrollview with buttons and applying gradient with conditions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a complex project, but I created a sample app to get help, so the code and colors used for gradient may not look professional. Anyways, I have a scrollview which has list of buttons. I only wish to show 3 buttons at a time, so I have reduced the height of VStack and user can scroll when they wish to look at other options.

*Here are the conditions:*

- Any center button should never have the gradient, only top visible and bottom visible button should have the gradient, so user knows there is more to scroll.
- If anytime, top or bottom button is selected, then that button should not have gradient i.e. for 3 buttons (top, center and bottom), if top is selected, then top should not have the gradient, center should not have the gradient as per condition 1 and only bottom will have the gradient in this case.

Selected button is button with blue border. There will always be one of the visible buttons selected and it could be either top, center or bottom button.

With my code all except the selected button has gradients. With SwiftUI, I am not fining an easy way to know which button is presently on the display and where are they located on the display. Is what I am trying to achieve, achievable with ScrollView?

[image]
[image]
[image]

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

@main
struct SampleAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().frame(maxHeight: 140.0)
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleTestData {
    let id = UUID()
    let score: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentlySelectedData: Int?
    
    let results = [
        SimpleTestData(score: 8),
        SimpleTestData(score: 5),
        SimpleTestData(score: 10),
        SimpleTestData(score: 15),
        SimpleTestData(score: 1)
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(results, id: \.id) { result in
                        makeDataButton(data: result.score).frame(height: 40.0).padding([.bottom, .top], 2.0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func makeDataButton(data: Int) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(data)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.currentlySelectedData = data
                }
                .background {
                    if currentlySelectedData == data {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .frame(width: 40 - 3, height: 40 - 3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .border(Color.blue)
                            .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.1), radius: 3.5, x: 0, y: 1.0)
                    }
                }
                .overlay {
                    if currentlySelectedData != data {
                        LinearGradient(
                            gradient: Gradient(
                                colors: [Color.gray.opacity(0.2), Color.clear]
                            ),
                            startPoint: .top,
                            endPoint: .bottom
                        )
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        .transition(.opacity)
                        .frame(width: 39.0, height: 39.0)
                    }
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you're telling it to.

You're telling it to add an overlay if the selected currentlySelectedData does not equal the passed in value.  But what you should be checking is if the value is the first or last in the array AND does not equal the passed in value.

Quickest fix is to change:

```
if currentlySelectedData != data {
```

to:

```
if results.first?.score == data && currentlySelectedData != data || results.last?.score == data && currentlySelectedData != data {
```

This should solve your simple case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your solution would definitely work if my question was showing all items in the array and adding gradient to first and last, but I am only showing 3 items at a time in scrollview, so can't really check for first and last in the array. I wouldn't know which 3 items out of 5 are visible in the scroll view and I am not seeing any Apple API to find it out.

Comment: Ahh I see.  In that case, I'd switch up the tactics and look into using geometry reader.  But even then, it might be more hassle than it's worth.  How much are you tied to the design?  Why not use the system picker with the .wheel style?

Comment: I am learning more about GeometryReader now. Even if I can somehow get visible scores, I can adjust the logic accordingly. I tried using LazyVStack instead of VStack while making buttons, but that didn't give me accurate visible rows. System picker would be my last resort, since with the knowledge I have, I don't think it allows to limit the visible options 3, leaves bunch of white space on top and bottom and may not allow me to style the selected option. I have to show only 3 options at a time.